# Exception while calling authenticate method of Zend Authentication Service

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-framework3

I'm migrating my ZF2 app to ZF3.

While calling the authenticate method, getting this exception

> An error occurred
>   An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
>   No Exception available

This is how I' calling the method,

```
public function __construct($authService, $sessionManager, $config)
{
    $this->authService = $authService;//Getting the Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService object (no error here)
    $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    $this->config = $config;
}
public function login($email, $password, $rememberMe)
{
    if ($this->authService->getIdentity() != null) {
        throw new \Exception('Already logged in');
    }

    // Authenticate with login/password.
    $authAdapter = $this->authService->getAdapter();
    $authAdapter->setEmail($email);//abc.gmail.com
    $authAdapter->setPassword($password);//sha1 password
    $this->authService->authenticate();//Exception is generating here
}
```

What is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Tell us something more about authentication service. Does it come from external module? Or it is standard Zend class?

Comment: @SzymonM It is a standard Zend class. The object of `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService`

Answer (score 0):

Your exception message is not enough, 
you should check **php_error.log** for details.

I assume that you are not registered Auth Service in the config.

So in **config/autoload/global.php** add

```
'service_manager' => [
    'invokables' => [
        Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService::class => Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService::class,
    ]
],
```